# can reinforcement learning agent learn a discrete distribution

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In a grid-world if i start taking actions following initial policy as a discrete distribution among available actions. let say i have at each state four actions (north, south, east, west), now i decide that in each state 50% of the time i will choose action "north". 30 % time i will choose action "south". 10 % time action "east" and rest 10% action "west". what effect it will have on optimal policy. if i had chosen uniform random distribution among actions. i guess that exploring an action more frequently will let q value for that state and action pair will converge fast and it will be more authentic. but no way if i explore an action more its q-value will be more. please tell me if i am correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your distribution allows you to get to any state in your world, then there will be no effect as your number of episodes approaches infinity. That is, you will obtain *exactly* the same optimal policy (assuming there is only one optimal policy) regardless of the probability distribution from which you draw your actions.

Of course this applies in theory, but in practice you may notice another side-effect of changing the probability distribution.

Assume that you are in a world that allows you to only select *left* or *right*. If the goal is always on the left and the probability of choosing the *left* action is 99%, you will obtain the optimal policy very very quickly. If the probability of choosing the *left* action is 1%, then you will obtain the optimal policy very very slowly. Either way, with enough episodes, you will obtain the optimal policy.

The same applies to e-greedy methods where the probability distribution may change during the episode.

Comment: So that means where ever our goal is it's always safe to take action using uniform random distribution among available actions. because then we will   always find the optimal policy in mean no of iterations (between minimum and no of episode approaching infinity). and taking action following distribution has no special benefit until unless i have special information about goal state. like as you mentioned "goal is always on the left".

Comment: I think I would shy away from saying it is *always* safe to use a uniform random distribution. Any distribution is safe so long as it is possible to get to every state while following that distribution. Certain distributions may have a benefit of faster convergence according to the environment. This may be the case even with no further knowledge of the environment, but found only through experimentation.